# Quick Links for global navigation

Tags: site-collection, navigation, quick-launch

In our SharePoint we have a global navigation that is shared across all site collections on the top of each page. On a team site level we'd like to use Quick launch navigation (i.e. the navigation on the left hand side). Is it possible to setup a site collection in a way it automatically synchronizes this Quick launch menu? I.e. I'd like to achieve that when I for example add a new item to the Quick launch on top site level, it automatically appears in all sub-sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 there is the option to enable `Managed Navigation: The navigation items will be represented using a Managed Metadata term set.`

This is under Site Settings > Navigation > Current Navigation (Quicklaunch)

[image]

I'm sure that there are other ways/techniques but this is a cool fully ootb feature that would keep a global navigation throughout the sites.

> SharePoint 2013 introduces managed metadata based navigation. It
>   provides the ability to apply friendly URLs to pages. The Navigation
>   items can be managed using the term store or Managed Metadata.  It
>   allows you to create and update navigation for all sites in the farm
>   using the Managed Metadata Service Application.

More:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15876.sharepoint-2013-navigation-using-managed-metadata.aspx